# Unity detecting user no longer holding button

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'd like to have a button displayed on screen, and as long as it's held, the user would turn.

This is how I created the button, and how I tried marking when the button is held:

```
if (GUI.Button (new Rect (OffsetUI, Screen.height - OffsetUI * 7, OffsetUI * 6, OffsetUI * 6), "left")) {
    playerScript.LeftButtonHeld = true;
}
else {
    playerScript.LeftButtonHeld = false;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. I believe the button gets into 'if' statement, whenever the button is clicked (on finger up).

How can I detect when a user is holding the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of GUI.Button, you will want to use GUI.RepeatButton as shown here:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.RepeatButton.html

Comment: It looks like I'm getting into the issue mentioned http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/repeatbutton-true-false.19527/ , that it gets called twice per frame, once with true, the other with false. But I think it can work out ... I'll just save last two calls and see if either of them is true.

Comment: No, don't do that. Use the Update function to handle your mouse-down logic instead of OnGUI. You'll see some comments about that in the thread you referenced. Good luck!